# How __iter__ works for printing linked list

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to learn linked lists and I'm stuck at the point where the instructor wrote down the `__iter__` method.

Although I particularly don't understand the part where it says `while node`, `node = node.next` and `print(node.value for node in singlyLinkedList)` I would be very grateful if you could explain `__iter__` and print parts in detail.

```
# step 1: defining class for creating head and tail pointers
class SLinkedList:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        # we cannot print this bcoz this is a custom data structure. 
        # so to be able to print this, we need to define 
        # a helper function
    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            yield node
            node = node.next

# step 2: class for creating node
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=None) -> None:
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

# step 3: assign value (create nodes)
singlyLinkedList = SLinkedList()
node1 = Node(1)
node2 = Node(2)
# step 4: create link between nodes and head & tail
singlyLinkedList.head = node1
singlyLinkedList.head.next = node2
singlyLinkedList.tail = node2

print(node.value for node in singlyLinkedList)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is one of these cases where Typing annotations makes thinks more easier, see [Python typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) for more info.
You are in the case of Singly linked list. Where a Singly linked list **contains nodes**. Each node has a data field `self.value` and a next field `self.next` which points to the next Node. Therefore:

```
class SLinkedList:
    def __init__(self, head: Node = None, tail: Node = None) -> None:
       self.head = head
       self.tail = tail

    ## here comes your iter dunder method

class Node:
    def __init__(self, value: int = None, next: Node = None) -> None:
        self.value = value
        self.next = next
```

Then you need to iterate through this nodes, but... Singly linked list only knows the value of the first node and the last node...
There is where your instructor comes with the idea of representing the iteration through the `__iter__` dunder method and the `yield` keyword.

The `yield` keyword is like a return, but it returns a **Generator**, see the answer from Neuron on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top) to know more about Generators and iterators, he explains it very well.

The `__iter__` dunder method in short words, is the pythonic method where to define the iteration process, you can define it in a custom named method 'customIterable' if you like, but `__iter__` is the best place, for standard purpose.
Then, your `__iter__` method can be read like this:

1. Take the first `Node` from the the Single linked list and store it locally in the variable called `node`
2. While `node` is different from `None` return the `Node` instance object stored in it. Then, set to the local variable `node` the `Node` instance stored in the `next` attribute of the current `Node`.

As you see at first glance seems a bit confusing, because the `yield` keyword seems exiting the loop, she is returning the current `Node` instance, how it continues looping?. The imperative to understand the `yield` keyword is to know that **when you set yield in the body of a function, when the function is called, the code inside it is not run, instead, a Generator object is returned**
This way, when you call your `SLinkedList` object instance inside a for .. in .. loop you are executing the code inside `__iter__` until reach `yield` then again, and again, ad nauseam.

This way, in the code executed in the first loop of the for loop is:

```
node = self.head
    while node:
        yield node
```

On the second iteration of the for loop the next line to execute is `node = node.next`, cronologically the code is executed until next `yield`like this:

```
node = node.next
# check the condition 'while node:'
yield node
```

In your case you only have two Nodes, a way to see your code better organized could be, using the code from below:

```
class SLinkedList:
    def __init__(self, head: Node = None, tail: Node = None) -> None:
        self.head = head
        self.tail = tail
    
    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            yield node
            node = node.next


class Node:
    def __init__(self, value: int = None, next: Node = None) -> None:
        self.value = value
        self.next = next


# Create nodes
node1 = Node(1)
node2 = Node(2)
node3 = Node(3)    

# Link the nodes
node1.next = node2
node2.next = node3 

# Create the Single Linked List 
singlyLinkedList = SLinkedList(node1, node3)

print([node.value for node in singlyLinkedList])
# [1, 2, 3]
```